# What is the position of "exclusive or" in order of precedence for logical connectives?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In propositional logic the order of precedence I have found for the logical connectives is

1. $\neg$
2. $\land$
3. $\lor$
4. $\Rightarrow$
5. $\Leftrightarrow$

Where do I have to put the exclusive or $\dot\lor$ in the above list?

Note: I also asked this question on this the German forum [matheboard.de](http://www.matheboard.de/thread.php?postid=1926793) two days ago. Because I did not get an answer there and because I also did not find an answer in the internet, I also want to ask this question here. I hope, this is okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exclusive-or can be thought of as "compound connective": a connective that involves $\lor$, $\land$ and $\lnot$ in any one of its forms:  $$p \dot\lor q \equiv (p \lor q) \land \lnot(p \land q)\equiv (p \lor q)\land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \equiv (p \land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land q)$$

Then the table of precedence you've posted covers exclusive-or, implicitly at least, as can be seen in the "expanded" versions of the exclusive-or.

Comment: For example: Where do I have to put the parentheses in the statement $A \lor B \,\dot\lor\, C \land D$?

Comment: That is ambiguous, if I've ever seen ambiguous.

Comment: Based on the [reasoning here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), I'd be inclined to suggest it's last in your list, following the biconditional, since it can be thought of as the negation of the biconditional. So for your example, $(A \lor B)\dot\lor(C\land D)$. But this is just speculation.

Comment: Would you agree, if we say, that there is no clear answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with that!.

Comment: Okay, as long as there are no other answers on this thread I will accept your answer. Thanks for your time! (Maybe you add to your answer a short note, that there is no clear answer, so that other do not have to read our comments...)

Answer (score 3):

'Exclusive or' ($\;\mathop{\dot \lor}\;$) is the negation of equivalence ($\;\Leftrightarrow\;$):
$$
(p \mathop{\dot \lor} q) \;\Leftrightarrow\; \lnot(p \Leftrightarrow q)
$$
Therefore personally I prefer to write equivalence as $\;\equiv\;$ and 'exclusive or' as $\;\not\equiv\;$, to make the duality clear in the symbols.

And when using those symbols, of course, I prefer to use the same precedence for both operators, and write e.g. $\;A \lor B \;\not\equiv\; C \land D\;$ without any parentheses.

Finally, note that not only is $\;\equiv\;$ associative, but also $\;\not\equiv\;$ is associative, and they are even *mutually* associative, so that we can write:
$$
p \not\equiv q \;\equiv\; \lnot(p \equiv q)
$$
without ambiguity.

---

On the same topic, I also dislike the precedence difference between $\;\land\;$ and $\;\lor\;$, as shown in your table.  One reason is the strong duality between both (which is hidden even more in boolean algebra notation).  But more importantly, a convention which makes $\;A \land B \lor C\;$ different from $\;A \land (B \lor C)\;$ can only lead to confusion, and instead it should be our goal as math writers to make the job as easy as possible on the math readers.

Therefore personally I never write $\;A \land B \lor C\;$, but instead always $\;(A \land B) \lor C\;$.

All of the above I did not invent myself, but I learned it from Dijkstra/Feijen/Scholten/Gries/Schneider.  See the article [E.W. Dijkstra, "The notational conventions I adopted, and why"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) (on-line), and also the books [E.W. Dijkstra and C.S. Scholten, "Predicate Calculus and Program Semantics"](https://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-1-4612-7924-2) and [D. Gries and F.B. Schneider, "A Logical Approach to Discrete Math"](https://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-0-387-94115-8).

---

And all this goes to show that precedence is a *convention*: one can get used to any convention, there are arguments for and against each one, and you don't "have to" put every operator in a specific place in the precedence list.

In case of doubt for a specific operator, you can always use parentheses so that the reader does not have to worry. Dijkstra also taught me to use more whitespace around lower precedence operators, as in
$$
p \;\equiv\; q \;\equiv\; p \land q \;\equiv\; p \lor q
$$
That also helps the reader in parsing, by suggesting the precedence.

Comment: I like brackets as well. However note when we use the `+` and `•` notation for `or` and `and`, it becomes clear that we can do algebraic tricks. e.g. `a•b + a•c ≡ a ( b + c )`, just like regular algebra.

Comment: @richard Yes. But note that in that case we also have $\;(a+b) • (a+c) \;\equiv\; a + (b•c)\;$ which is really unclear and counter-intuitive, which for me shows that using $\;+\;$ and $\;•\;$ for 'or' and 'and' is more trouble than it seems worth at first sight.

Comment: Sorry my example was bad, I realised as I slept (following posting it). What I should have said is 1+1=2=1, 1+0 =1, 0+0=0, 0•0=0, 0•1=0, 1•1=1. Except for 2=1 it is like regular algebra.